# How to print an nth column in a file using awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have n files (call them input1, input2, and so on) with similar data and I wish to make a new file (call it out) that contains the 2nd column of these files. If I use

```
awk '{print $2}' input{1..n} >> out
```

then I get a single column with all the entries from the 2nd column of the input files. What can I do to have different columns for different files, as in `$1` in out = `$2` of input1, `$2` in out = `$2` of input2, `$3` in out = `$2` of input3,....., `$n` in out = `$2` of inputn?

Comment: Are all files of the same length, i.e. do they all always have the same number of rows, and is this number known in advance?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes they're all of the same length and the #rows and #columns are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the whole thing in a `BEGIN` statement using `getline`

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    while(1) {
      line = sep = ""
      for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
        if ((getline < ARGV[i]) <= 0) exit
        line = line sep $2
        sep = OFS
      }
      print line
    }
  }' input{1..n} > out
```

Comment: Is there any way we can use `ORS`? I was trying that but it doesn't work with multiple files.

Comment: @PRY, there was a missing loop. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Sorry, I was asking in general manner, not related to your answer.

Comment: @PRY, that code uses ORS. `print line` prints the content of the `line` variable followed by that of ORS. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas can you explain the condition within if, I don't understand `getline' properly?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania, `getline` retrieves one record from the given input file and return 0 upon end-of-file or a negative number upon error in which case we exit (so we stop as soon as we've reached the end of any of the input files so the number of records in the output file is that of the input file with fewest records).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas wouldn't this also store everything in the memory (variable line) before printing?

Comment: @HitanshuSachania, not it builds one line of output (in `line`) at a time, as opposed to storing all the lines of output in an array and printing it at the end. We could skip  storing the line in `line` and print the fields as they come, but that would cause problem for the last record if not all input files have the same number of records.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas understood. It works perfectly fine. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You could construct a `paste` command to put all the second columns together:

```
cmd="paste"
for x in input{1..n}; do
   cmd="$cmd <(awk '{print \$2;}' $x)"
done
echo $cmd
eval $cmd
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the `pr` tool, which is designed to columnize data:

```
awk '{print $2}' input{1..n} | pr -t --columns=n > out
```

This assumes each file has the same number of lines.

Comment: The best answer for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26342838/extracting-columns-from-multiple-files-into-a-single-output-file-from-the-comman)   as reference

```
awk '{a[FNR] = a[FNR]" " $2}END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i]}' input{1..n}
```

an array holds each line from different files

FNR number of records read in current input file, set to zero at begining of each file.

```
END{for(i=1;i<FNR;i++) print a[i]}
```

prints the content of array a on END of file

Comment: What is the purpose of the double quotes before $2 and how does the array a store just the 2nd column?

Comment: Note that it stores the whole output in memory  before starting to print it.

Comment: I changed  the lstaro of the loop froom 0 to 1

Comment: the double quotes before $2 defile the delimiter between columns in the output file and the script is passing the value in $2 to  a[FNR] element of the array

Comment: Use `{a[FNR]=!a[FNR]?$2:a[FNR]" "$2}` to eleminate white space in front of each line...